# PrimeNG calendar form group validation issue

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm trying to add validation to my form.

`discount` field cannot be empty and value range needs to be within 0 to 100, `time_from` and `time_to` cannot be empty. I cannot fire validation proccess on `time_from` and `time_to`. I use PrimeNG Calendar component. I found out that `p-calendar` validation works great with `ngModule`, but I couldnt find any solution for form groups.

**Component (simplified)**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.discountFG = this.fb.group({
      discount: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.range([0, 100])]),
      time_from: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      time_to: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });

    this.discountFG.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
  }

  onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.discountFG) { return; }
    const form = this.discountFG;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Template (simplified)**

```
          <p-calendar formControlname="time_from" [locale]="pl" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
            yearRange="2010:2030" (blur)="setTimeFrom($event)" readonlyInput="true" required></p-calendar>

          <p-calendar formControlname="time_to" [locale]="pl" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
            yearRange="2010:2030" [minDate]="minDate" readonlyInput="true" required></p-calendar>
```

**Current behavior**

Validators dont notice if date is picked and because of this, no event is fired to catch value change, which means `onValueChanged` thinks `time_from` and `time_to` is untouched.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some extensive debugging, I found out the form wasn't validating because of a syntax error :(, you spelled `formControlName` with lowercase `n`. At least, that's the case for the code you posted. Because of that, form controls were never getting the values.

I fixed it in Plunk and tried, it started working.

html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="discountFG" class="box-model form-support-margin">
  <p-calendar formControlName="time_from" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
            yearRange="2010:2030" (blur)="setTimeFrom($event)" readonlyInput="true">

  </p-calendar>

          <p-calendar formControlName="time_to" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
            yearRange="2010:2030" [minDate]="minDate" readonlyInput="true"></p-calendar>
  <p></p>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!discountFG.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/X0cmeJjqd80J0fGrXFTR?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Nehal, I have been so blind, I've wasted half of a day just to see 2 misspelled `n`'s :)

Comment: Don't feel bad, took me a while to notice too :)